# "the museum didn’t open vs the museum wasn’t open"

Tags: past-simple

> The museum **wasn’t open** at 9 a.m.
>
> The museum **didn’t open** at 9 a.m.

1. Could you explain please the difference in their meaning? I understand the first "open" is an adjective but the second "open" is a verb. So, what is the difference in their usage?
2. I can't understand how the museum can open itself. It seems like a joke.

> He didn't open the museum at 9 a.m. - OK
>
> The museum didn’t open at 9 a.m. - ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The museum wasn’t open at 9 a.m.

A prospective visitor arrived at nine and found it closed.

> The museum didn’t open at 9 a.m.

9 a.m. was not the time when it opened (it might have happened earlier or later).

It's no joke to refer to a shop, museum etc. 'opening' - it's just simpler than saying 'the staff opened it', and perfectly normal.

Comment: @Sergei The apparent "joke" is about *open* having both transitive and intransitive versions—that is, you can "open" a door, or a flower can "open." (Confusingly, it can also be a participle or "adjective.") We're not using a reflexive verb when a flower "opens," not saying it "opens itself," just using a different usage of the verb.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, If I understand you correctly, the both version can be used: **"The museum wasn’t open at 9 a.m. last Sunday, it was open at 10 a.m." & "The museum didn’t open at 9 a.m. last Sunday, it opened at 10 a.m."**

Comment: @Sergei if you say the museum "was open" at 9, you are talking about it being in state of allowing entrance to visitors. If you say the museum "opened at 9 am" you're talking about the moment it changed from being closed to being open.

Comment: I tried to show the difference in my answer.